# undefined method despite method being defined

Tags: php, class, codeigniter, fatal-error

Having a very strange issue with an error on a codeigniter site.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Document::get_by_module()
```

The line of code causing this (in a controller) is:

```
$this->document_type->get_by_module('module1');
```

The constructor of the controller:

```
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('document','document_type');
}
```

The document_type class looks like this

```
class Document_type extends CI_Model {
    function Document_type () {
        parent::__construct();

    }       
    function get_by_module($prefix) {
        // code 
    }
}
```

The main issue I'm seeing is that it's saying `Document::` is the class, but it should be `Document_type`. I see no reason that it should be looking in the document class for that function.

If I remove loading of the 'document' class from the controller constructor, the error goes away (but other things break).

Not sure how something like that could be happening.

Comment: What happens when you don't load `document`?

Comment: that code works but I get errors from other places later on in that page/other pages.

Comment: I'm definitely aware of that. That's why I'm very confused about the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are loading in the wrong model file. The line

```
$this->load->model('document','document_type');
```

means something along the lines of: Find me a model named "Document" create an instance and put under `$this->document_type`. ([see the 4th example](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html#loading))

Looks like you have a `Document` model so the load succeeds, but if you don't want to rename your instance put under the `$this` (controller instance) you shouldn't use the second parameter in the `$this->load->model()` line.

Simply write `$this->load->model('document_type');`